# React Router make a "new page" after clicking on a card

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

guys anyone can help me with React Router

im trying to make a "new page"(with the project details) after someone click on my project card
but im not able to do that i been looking all around to find a solution
but i dont want create a new button to handel this changes.
this is my code :

```
import React from "react";
import data from "../data";
import Proj from "./proj";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  useParams,
} from "react-router-dom";
import ProjectDetails from "./projectsDetail";

//do something...
function Projects(props) {
  function Child() {
    // We can use the `useParams` hook here to access
    // the dynamic pieces of the URL.
    let { id } = useParams();

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>ID: {id}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="projects">
        <div className="">
          {data.map((item, i) => {
            return (
              <div key={i}>
                <Router>
                  <Link to={`/${item.name}`}>
                    <Proj
                      key={i}
                      name={item.name}
                      details={item.details}
                      img={item.img}
                    />
                  </Link>

                  <Route
                    path="/:id"
                    children={<ProjectDetails id={item.id} name={item.name} />}
                  />
                </Router>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Projects;
```

im getting new url but it's not in a new Page . its just appears on the same page

Comment: Do you mean that it is not opening in a new tab? If that is what you want, use {target="_blank"} in the Link tag.

Comment: I want to open it in the same tab , and that old page (that contain all my projects) will "reset to blank page" with the specific project details

Comment: You should not be creating multiple `Router` elements via map for a start - only one is required and should be placed at the top level of your application. All that a `Route` element does is conditionally render some JSX based on matches with the url. In client-side routing, a 'New Page' is an abstraction which you need to implement yourself. You will need to define distinct routes for both `/` and `/:id`, with `/` containing the links and `/:id` containing the details.

Comment: @lawrence-witt finally !! it works thanks ,how do i  define distinct routes ? 
the logic is that :
if im on localhost:3000/ show this components  and if im on localhost:3000/:id show me other componets?

Comment: That's right. Take a look at the [example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic) given by the React Router docs. You can think of different pages as different collections of components, often grouped into their own top level components and referred to as 'Views'.

Comment: i did somthing like that and its working now , is this  a good practice?
'''
      {location.pathname !== "/" ? null : (
        <div>
          <Header />
          <h1
            style={{
              textDecoration: "underline",
              textDecorationColor: "lightblue",
            }}
          >
            My Projects
          </h1>

          <Projects />
          <About />
          <Code />
        </div>
"''